# hourly action resetter with threading

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

this is some code I have written based off basic knowledge of threading I acquired. What I am trying to do is limit the actions hourly so it doesn't spam.

```
import datetime
import time
from threading import Thread

the_Minute   = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())[3:5]
action_Limit = 0

def updater():
    global the_Minute
    while True:
        the_Minute=str(datetime.datetime.now().time())[3:5]
        #updates the minute value

def resetter():
    global action_Limit
    global the_Minute
    while True:
        if the_Minute=='00':
            action_Limit=0
        time.sleep(30)


def performer():
    global action_Limit
    global the_Minute
    while the_Minute!='00' and action_Limit<100:
        #perform actions here
        action_Limit+=1
        print(action_Limit)
        time.sleep(1)

updater_Thread   = Thread(target=updater)
resetter_Thread  = Thread(target=resetter)
performer_Thread = Thread(target=performer)

updater_Thread.start
performer_Thread.start
resetter_Thread.start
```

When I run this, nothing happens, but I also don't receive any errors. Could anyone tell me how I could make it work, or point me to some resources to help? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your `resetter` method has a rather tight loop there. Could you add a `time.sleep` call to only check the minute every second (or more)?

Comment: If you start your `performer` thread last, is `the_Minute` defined as local in the other methods? Maybe the `global` definitions should be defined at the top?

Comment: I changed the code @BernhardHofmann, thank you for the suggestions! Each of the functions declare `the_Minute` as global.

Comment: Does it work yet?

Comment: It does not still

Comment: Wish I could help but I'm away from my PC and my employer blocks me from installing Python so I can't learn it and test possible solutions. :(

Comment: It’s all good! I made it work, thanks for your help

Comment: Please post your answer (yes, you can answer your own questions) and then someone else can learn from it.